# jQuery adding multiple element from array of objects into HTML

Tags: jquery

First, let me say that I am a noob in JS and jQuery, and I apologize if I make some tech mistakes. 
I have a problem creating single  element with multiple entries from the object that I have.

My problem is that I "fetched" some data from the internet (to be exact, from randomuser.me). I fetched 20 users and put them in one .js file. In another file, I am trying to pull only certain elements from those objects and via jQuery to make HTML.

```
<HTML>
    <div id="okvir"></div>
</HTML>
<script>
    for (i = 0; i <= korisnici.results.length; i++) 
{
    $("#okvir").append("<div class=blah></div>");
    $(".blah").append("<h1>"+korisnici.results[i].name.first+"</h1>"),
    $(".blah").append("<p>"+korisnici.results[i].email+"</p>"),
    $(".blah").append("<p>"+korisnici.results[i].phone+"</p>")
    $(".blah").append(`<img 
    src="${korisnici.results[i].picture.medium}">`) 
};

</script>
```

what I am getting with is: 20 new 'div' elements inside 
'div id="okvir"  '/div' with 20 object elements in each 'div'.

I need to create 20 separate 'div class="blah"' elements with only certain data from fetched file to each 'div class="blah"' container.

1. korisnici.results[i].name.first
2. korisnici.results[i].email
3. korisnici.results[i].phone
4. korisnici.results[i].picture.medium

Thank you all in advance. 
I hope that I wasn't that bad in explaining what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `$('.blah')` is a global selector and is going to find all of them that you create.

```js
for (i = 0; i <= korisnici.results.length; i++) {
  var $div = $("<div class=blah></div>");

  $div.append("<h1>" + korisnici.results[i].name.first + "</h1>"),
  $div.append("<p>" + korisnici.results[i].email + "</p>"),
  $div.append("<p>" + korisnici.results[i].phone + "</p>")
  $div.append(`<img src="${korisnici.results[i].picture.medium}">`)

  $("#okvir").append($div);
};
```

Make the element, append to it, and then append the one element to the existing parent.

SIDE NOTE: Given that you are using template literals for the image, this entire block could be one append statement if it was all in a single template literal statement.